# Ray Sphere Intersect Problom

Tags: vectors, 3d, intersection-theory

I'm making a 3D game and I have the following function to detect if a gun firing a laser beam (straight line) intersects a spherical object.

```
boolean intersect(Point3D raydir, Point3D rayorig, Point3D pos, double rad) {
        double a = raydir.X * raydir.X + raydir.Y * raydir.Y + raydir.X * raydir.X;
        double b = raydir.X * 2.0f * (rayorig.X - pos.X) + raydir.Y * 2.0f * (rayorig.Y - pos.Y) + raydir.Z * 2.0f * (rayorig.Z - pos.Z);
        double c = sum(pos, pos) + rayorig.X * rayorig.X + rayorig.Y * rayorig.Y + rayorig.Z * rayorig.Z -
                2.0f*(rayorig.X * pos.X + rayorig.Y * pos.Y + rayorig.Z * pos.Z) - rad * rad;
        double D = b*b + (-4.0f)*a*c;
        return ( D < 0 );
    }
```

So if my gun is located at (50,50,50) and the sphere is located at (50, 100, 50) with a radius of 5.0 and the weapon fires toward (50,40,50) which is the oposite direction to the sphere the math above return true.

```
intersect((50, 40, 50) , (50, 50, 50), (50, 100, 50), 5.0); //returns true
```

Comment: anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have
$$\begin{array}
\vec{o} = (x_o, y_o, z_o) & \text{ Ray origin } \\
\vec{d} = (x_d, y_d, z_d) & \text{ Ray direction } \\
\vec{c} = (x_c, y_c, z_c) & \text{ Sphere center } \\
r \gt 0 & \text{ Sphere radius }
\end{array}$$

This means the points $\vec{p}(t)$ on the ray fulfill
$$\vec{p}(t) = \vec{o} + t \vec{d}$$
with $t \ge 0$.

---

The ray origin is within the sphere if and only if
$$\left( \vec{c} - \vec{o} \right) \cdot \left( \vec{c} - \vec{o} \right) \le r^2$$
In pseudocode:

```
Boolean IsInsideSphere(Vec3D o, Vec3D c, Real r):
    return ( ( (o.x - c.x)*(o.x - c.x) + 
               (o.y - c.y)*(o.y - c.y) +
               (o.z - c.z)*(o.z - c.z) ) <= r*r )
```

---

The center of the sphere is in the same hemisphere (halfspace) as the direction of the ray, if and only if
$$\left( \vec{c} - \vec{o} \right) \cdot \vec{d} \ge 0$$
In pseudocode:

```
Boolean SameHalfspace(Vec3D o, Vec3D d, Vec3D c):
    return ( ( (c.x - o.x) * d.x + 
               (c.y - o.y) * d.y +
               (c.z - o.z) * d.z ) >= 0 )
```

---

The minimum distance, squared, between the ray (infinitely long, extending to both directions) and the center of the sphere (from [Point-Line Distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) at Wolfram Mathworld) is
$$r_{min}^2 = \frac{ \left\lvert \vec{d} \times \left( \vec{c} - \vec{o} \right) \right\rvert^2 }{ \left\lvert \vec{d} \right\rvert^2 } = \frac{ \left( \vec{d} \times \left( \vec{c} - \vec{o} \right) \right) \cdot \left( \vec{d} \times \left( \vec{c} - \vec{o} \right) \right) }{ \vec{d} \cdot \vec{d} }$$ 
In pseudocode:

```
Real MinimumDistanceSquared(Vec3D o, Vec3D d, Vec3D c)
    Vec3D t = (c.x - o.x, c.y - o.y, c.z - o.z)
    Real dd = d.x*d.x + d.y*d.y + d.z*d.z
    if (dd > 0.0):
        Vec3D p = ( d.y*t.z - d.z*t.y,
                    d.z*t.x - d.x*t.z,
                    d.x*t.y - d.y*t.x )
        return (p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y + p.z*p.z) / dd
    else:
        # No direction, return the distance squared.
        return t.x*t.x + t.y*t.y + t.z*t.z
```

---

The complete ray-hits-sphere test is then

```
Boolean RayHitsSphere(Vec3D o, Vec3D d, Vec3D c, Real r)

    # If you are inside the sphere, you cannot miss it.
    if (IsInsideSphere(o, c, r)):
        return True

    # We cannot hit the sphere, if we are facing away.
    if (not SameHalfSpace(o, d, c)):
        return False

    # Actual intersection test.
    return (MinimumDistanceSquared(o, d, c) <= r*r)
```

In a real-world game, you could give better score the closer the ray passes to the center of the sphere. Instead of the above Boolean function, you could have it return `0.0` for a miss, and `1.0` for a perfect hit (within some fraction of `r` of the center), and some value inbetween for imperfect hits.